# Различия copy функций в shutil

Tags: python, python-3.x, shutil

Есть библиотека **Python3 shutil** с методами:

- copyfileobj
- copyfile
- copymode
- copystat
- copy
- copy2
- copytree
- ignore_patterns

Вопросы:

1. В чём разница между этими методами? Кратко, если не трудно объясните в какой ситуации каждый применяется?
2. Например не очень понятно как копируются метаданные без самого файла, куда именно? И наоборот файлы отдельно от метаданных, откуда тогда метаданные берутся?
3. Если нужно обычное копирование файла, то что из этого использовать?

Comment: К copytree еще полезно знать про distutils.dir_util.copy_tree, который более полезен

Comment: Ответы на все свои вопросы вы можете найти в официальной документации https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html

Comment: @andreymal, к сожалению официальная документация не вносит ясности для меня, видимо преградой является английский, я пробовал на русском информацию поискать, но не нашёл, поэтому и задал вопрос здесь

Comment: @vitidev, мне бы с этим сначала разобраться

Comment: Старайтесь менее обширные вопросы задавать. К примеру, если какие-то детали не ясны, то отдельные вопросы задайте: "как copymode() работает, не копируя самого файла", итд. Тогда опираясь на известные детали, можно  вопрос задать: "какую из copyfile, copy, copy2 функций следует использовать в моей ситуации для копирования файла" — где вопрос подробно описывает вашу конкретную ситуацию ("резервное копирование"/на флешку, для переноса на другую машину/итд).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> (1) В чём разница между этими методами? Кратко если не трудно объясните в какой ситуации каждый применяется?

Если чтение документации [`shutil.copyfileobj()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj)не достаточно для вас, то можно посмотреть на [исходный код](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d4b93e21c2664d6a78e0656e7a7be0807be1c352/Lib/shutil.py#L76-L82):

```
def copyfileobj(fsrc, fdst, length=16*1024):
    """copy data from file-like object fsrc to file-like object fdst"""
    while 1:
        buf = fsrc.read(length)
        if not buf:
            break
        fdst.write(buf)
```

То есть: пытаемся прочитать кусок, заданной длины, из входного файла и если что-то прочитали, то пишем это в выходной файл, иначе завершаем цикл — всё. Можно использовать для копирования содержимого между любыми файло-подобными объектами (с методами `read()`, `write()`).

[`copyfile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile) принимает пути, а не сами файлы (отсюда отличия). Если на входе пути к обычным файлам, то [`copyfile(src, dst)` сводится к простому](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d4b93e21c2664d6a78e0656e7a7be0807be1c352/Lib/shutil.py#L96-L123):

```
with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
        copyfileobj(fsrc, fdst)
```

Открыли файлы, скопировали содержимое.

> (2) Например не очень понятно как копируются метаданные без самого файла, куда именно? И наоборот файлы отдельно от метаданных, откуда тогда метаданные берутся?

[`copymode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copymode), [`copystat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copystat) сводится к чтению метаданных исходного файла и применению их к выходному файлу (копирование режима доступа против копирования режима доступа + времени доступа/изменения + флаги, то есть просто chmod против utime + chmod + chflags + setxattr соответственно). Документация явно говорит, что конкретно должно быть скопировано.

Если выходной файл не существует, то не к чему применять метаданные и эти функции завершатся с ошибкой (`FileNotFoundError`).

Само содержимое файлов, кто владелец, группа, к которой файл принадлежит, не меняются этими функциями.

Когда явно не копируются метаданные, то используются значения по умолчанию (к примеру, может зависеть от значения [umask](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask)).

> (3) Если нужно обычное копирование файла, то что из этого использовать?

Это зависит от того какой смысл вы вкладываете в слова *"обычное копирование"*.

[`copy()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy) и [`copy2()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy2) это просто `copyfile()` вызов, за которым идёт `copymode()` и `copystat()` соответственно. Дополнительно, эти функции в отличии от `copyfile()` могут принимать папку куда писать.

Документация явно упоминает, что `copy(src, dst)` это [`cp src dst`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html), а `copy2(src, dst)` это `cp -p src dst`. Вторая команда больше метаданных старается скопировать: разрешения на чтение/запись/исполнение, владелец, время модификации/доступа (`copy2()` в отличии от `cp -p` не копирует владельца).

[`copytree()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree) рекурсивно копирует всё дерево директорий, так что тяжело её перепутать с другими функциями. `copytree()` по умолчанию использует `copy_function=copy2` для копирования обычных файлов.

[`ignore_patterns(*patterns)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.ignore_patterns) возвращает функцию, которая может быть использована в качестве значения `ignore` параметра при вызове `copytree()` (`ignore(src, names)` функция возвращает те имена из `names=os.listdir(src)`, которые не должны копироваться из `src` директории, соответствующей текущему рекурсивному вызову). [Полезно на примеры посмотреть](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#copytree-example):

```
copytree(source, destination, ignore=ignore_patterns('*.pyc', 'tmp*'))
```

`source` папка рекурсивно копируется в новую `destination` папку, игнорируя имена с расширением `.pyc` или начинающиеся на `tmp` ([glob-шаблоны, как в командной строке](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0)).

Answer (score 0):

`copyfile` копирует только данные,в то время как `copy` копирует ещё бит разрешений. `Copyfile` работает быстрее `copy`. `Copyfile ()` вызывает метод `copyfileobj ()`, тогда как `copy ()` работает путем вызова функций `copyfile ()` и `copystat ()`. Вызов `shutil.copytree()` создает новую папку с именем my_scripts_backup с тем же содержимым, что и исходная папка my_scripts. Например :

```
import shutil, os
os.chdir('C:\\')
shutil.copytree('C:\\my_scripts', 'C:\\my_scripts_backup')
```

Comment: а что значит только данные? Ну я понимаю что это содержимое файла, но не понимаю в какой ситуации это нужно и откуда берутся недостающие элементы. У каждого файла есть содержимое, есть имя файла, есть права доступа, даты 3 штуки (доступа, модификации, создания), может ещё что забыл упомянуть - ведь это имеется ввиду под метаинформацией?

Comment: неточность: `copy()` вызывает `copymode()`, а не `copystat()`. Совсем по мелочи: s/бит/биты/ (больше одного бита на доступ отводится). `os.chdir('C:\\')` не нужен.