# Сравнение строк при сохранении файла работает некорректно

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

Здравствуйте.
Есть папка с изображениями(1) и текстовый файл с названиями изображений (2).
Пишу код, который проверял бы наличие в папке тех картинок, которые есть в текстовом файле, копировал те, что есть и в (1), и в (2) в одну папку, а те, что есть только в папке, но не указаны в файле - в другую. Первая часть работает хорошо, вторая - нет.

Вот программа:

```
import os, glob
from PIL import Image

cropped = [img for img in glob.glob('/Users/mac/PycharmProjects/Work/cropped/*.png')]
labeled_db = '/Users/mac/PycharmProjects/Work/Labeled Dataset part 1.txt'


name = []
items = []
def label():

    for img in cropped:
        im = Image.open(img)
        name_line = os.path.basename(img).split('_')
        print(name_line[0])
        with open(labeled_db) as f:
            for line in f:
                items_name = line.split('_')
                if items_name[0] == name_line[0] :
                    save_fname = os.path.join('/Users/mac/PycharmProjects/Work/1', os.path.basename(name_line[0]) + '.png')
                    im.save(save_fname)  #досюда всё хорошо работает
```

## первый вариант

```
 else:
                save_fname2 = os.path.join('/Users/mac/PycharmProjects/Work/0',
                                          os.path.basename(name_line[0]) + '.png')
                im.save(save_fname2)
```

Второй вариант (добавил к имеющемуся if'у):

```
 if items_name[0] != name_line[0] :
                save_fname2 = os.path.join('/Users/mac/PycharmProjects/Work/0',
                                          os.path.basename(name_line[0]) + '.png')
                im.save(save_fname2)
label()
```

В третьем случае я вместо первого условия с "==" написал " !=" и '.../Work/0', чтобы только сохранение в "0" работало, но всё равно не пашет.
Выводил print(name_line[0]) при not in - вывод застревал на 1 записи; то же самое делал при "==" - всё выводит, как надо.
Почему так происходит и что я упускаю, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: `split` для чего нужен? Пример названия файла дайте.

Comment: @Эникейщик, после названия файла идёт всякий мусор, записанный после "_", и чтобы сравнивать, нужно отбросить всё после него.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы скопировать png-картинки в одну папку, если имя встречается в текстовом файле, и скопировать в другую папку, если нет (не тестировано):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import shutil
from pathlib import Path

src_dir = Path('/путь/к папке/с картинками')
dest_dirs = [Path('/путь/к папке/с картинками НЕ из txt файла'),
             Path('/путь/к папке/с картинками из txt файла')]
pictures = frozenset(Path('picture-names.txt').read_text().splitlines())
for path in src_dir.glob('*.png'):
    shutil.copy2(path, dest_dirs[path.stem in pictures])
```

Пример, что `path.stem` делает:

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> Path('/dir/flower.png').stem
'flower'
```

Чтобы понять почему `shutil.copy2()`, а не к примеру `shutil.copy()` используется см., [Различия copy функций в shutil](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/705214/23044).

Comment: спасибо, но выдаётся ошибка AttributeError: 'Path' object has no attribute 'read_text'

Comment: @TheDoctor: [`pathlib.Path.read_text`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.read_text)

Comment: можно уточнить, пожалуйста: имеется в виду pathlib или path, или импортировать надо оба? Просто и там, и там есть Path, и read_text есть у pathlib.

Comment: @TheDoctor изначально только pathlib из стандартной библиотеки модуль должен был быть (path это опечатка была)

Comment: аааа, всё понял, спасибо большое, ща тестить буду.